# NODEJS : Want To Create an Array of objects, with only one key's value set to empty in each Object

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, javascript-objects

**I have**

```
obj1 = {
    "place": "{{base_gplaceId}}",
    "subPlace": "{{base_gsubPlaceId}}",
    "user": "{{base_userId}}",
};
```

**I want**

```
var newArr = [{
    "place": "",
    "subPlace": "{{base_gsubPlaceId}}",
    "user": "{{base_userId}}",
}, {
    "place": "{{base_gplaceId}}",
    "subPlace": "",
    "user": "{{base_userId}}"
}, {
    "place": "{{base_gplaceId}}",
    "subPlace": "{{base_gsubPlaceId}}",
    "user": ""
}];
```

**Following is my Code**

```
var newArr = [];
const obj1 = {
    "place": "{{base_gplaceId}}",
    "subPlace": "{{base_gsubPlaceId}}",
    "user": "{{base_userId}}",
};

KEYS = Object.keys(obj1);

KEYS.forEach(function (element) {
    var object2 = null;

    console.log("init:", object2);

    object2 = obj1;

    console.log("object2:", object2);

    console.log("element:", element);

    console.log("object2 element VAL:", object2[element]);

    object2[element] = "";

    console.log("OBJ VAL:", object2, "\n---------------");

    newArr.push(object2);
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Some how mid way obj1 is being set to empty values, and hence object2 is being set with empty values not getting Expected Values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are assigned by reference. When you set `object2 = obj1;` and then change `object2`, `obj1` will change as well. Doing that in a loop causes the side effects you're seeing.

Copy the object using `object2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);` instead.

Comment: Thanks, That Worked!!